# Multiple strings have special characters in regex

Tags: c#, regex

> I am new to Regular expression, I have a requirement to find "/./" or
>   "/../" in a string. My program look likes as follow,

```
String Path1 = "https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/././Directory2/filename.txt";
String Path2 = https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/../../Directory2/filename.txt";
String Path3 = "https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/Directory2/filename.txt";

Regex nameRegex = new Regex(@"[/./]+[/../]");
bool b = nameRegex.IsMatch(OrginalURL);
```

This code giving true for Path3(dont have any "." or ".." strings) also.

It seems the expression "Regex nameRegex = new Regex(@"[/./]+[/../]");" is not true. Kindly correct this expression.

Regex match should be success for Path1 or Path2 and not Path3.

Comment: You could just do `bool b = path1.Contains("/./") || path1.Contains("/../");`. No need for a regex, easier to read and more performant.

Comment: I know this works but i am searching for a better way in regex so that in future i can add more strings or symbols if need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[/./]+[/../]` (=`[/.]+[/.]`) regex matches 1+ `/` or `.` chars followed with a `/` or `.`. It can thus match `....../`, `/////////////`, and certainly `//` in the protocol part.

If you do not have to use a regex you may simply use `.Contains`:

```
if (s.Contains("/../") || s.Contains("/./"))  { ... }
```

See this [C# demo](http://ideone.com/3DQAwp).

You may use the following regex, too:

```
bool b = Regex.IsMatch(OrginalURL, @"/\.{1,2}/");
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5c.%7b1%2c2%7d%2f&i=https%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2f.%2f.%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2f..%2f..%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2F%5C.%7B1%2C2%7D%2F):

[image]

**Details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `\.{1,2}` - 1 or 2 dots
- `/` - a `/` char.

Answer (score 0):

While this would not be the best way to do this task, an expression similar to:

```
\/\.{1,2}(?=\/)
```

might work.

#### [Demo](/.%7B1,2%7D(?=/))

> Escaping is just for demoing purpose, you can remove those.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\/\.{1,2}(?=\/)";
        string input = @"https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/./Directory2/filename.txt
https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/././Directory2/filename.txt
https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/../../../Directory2/filename.txt
https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/./../.../Directory2/filename.txt
https://18.56.199.56/Directory1/Directory2/filename.txt";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @wiktor expression is `/\.{1,2}/` not `\/\.{1,2}` as you said.

Comment: `/` is not any special regex metacharacter and does not have to be escaped in any .NET regex pattern. [This](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5c.%7b1%2c2%7d%2f&i=https%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2f.%2f.%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2f..%2f..%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2f18.56.199.56%2fDirectory1%2fDirectory2%2ffilename.txt) proves my solution is working.

Comment: @Emma, Solution provided by you is also working. Could you tell any example in which wiktor case would fail ?

Comment: @SreeAam Neither of my two solutions will fail.